# Scala: Are these two partial functions equivalent?

Tags: scala

Are these two partial functions equivalent?

```
val f0: PartialFunction[Int, String] = {
  case 10 => "ten"
  case n: Int => s"$n"
}

val f1 = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  override def isDefinedAt(x: Int): Boolean = true
  override def apply(v: Int): String = if (v == 10) "ten" else s"$v"
}
```

*UPD*

```
val pf = new PartialFunction[Int, String] {
  def isDefinedAt(x: Int) = x == 10
  def apply(v: Int) = if (isDefinedAt(v)) "ten" else "undefined"
}

def fun(n: Int)(pf: PartialFunction[Int, String]) = pf.apply(n)
println(fun(100)(pf))
```

Is it truly PF now?

Comment: They'll certainly always have the same behaviour, but may be represented differently in bytecode depending on the version of the scala compiler used.  Is that what you're asking? Also these aren't strictly partial functions as they are always defined...

Comment: I didn't get this `as they are always defined`. What do you mean?

Comment: Do I need to add `def fun(n: Int)(pf: PartialFunction[Int, String]): String = pf.apply(n)` to make `f0` and `f1` PartialFunctions?

Comment: The idea of having partial functions is that they may not be defined for some of their input values.  Yours are defined for all input values, so you might as well use plain functions.  That's what I mean by 'they are always defined'

Comment: You don't need to add anything to make them `PartialFunctions`....

Comment: Still don't understand exactly what you are asking.

Comment: @Finkelson After compiler compiles `f0`, it will generate the code that looks like `f1`. They are equivalent, yes. They are not equal (`f0 == f1`) because scala does not define `==` for partial functions. They are partial, but defined on the whole range - that's what @jazmit meant. if you'd remove second line `case n: Int = ...` and leave only the line `case 10` you would have defined the function only on the value `10`, so it would have been a truly partially defined function. In that case your `isDefinedAt` should be `= (x == 10)`, and `apply` can be just `= "ten"`

Comment: @Archeg Thanks, I see now.

Comment: However, if I remove the second case I can get `scala.MatchError`. So I suppose it is not the best practice, right? I mean to leave unhandled cases.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need 2 partial (value) functions to use the `PartialFunction` the way it is designed to be: one for the value 10, and the other for the other `Int`s:

```
val f0:PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case 10 => "ten" }
val fDef:PartialFunction[Int, String] = { case n => s"$n" }
```

And how to apply them:

```
val t1 = (9 to 11) collect f0
t1 shouldBe(Array("ten"))
val t2 = (9 to 11) map (f0 orElse fDef)
t2 shouldBe(Array("9", "ten", "11"))
```